# sympy - symbolic sum over symbolic number of elements

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, linear-equation

What is the most appropriate way to express the following in SymPy:

A sum over samples 'x[i]' with 'i' going from concrete
0 to symbolic 'N'. 'x[i]' itself shall be symbolic, i.e.
always appear as variable.

The goal is to use these expressions in a system of linear equations.

###### Example (trivial least squares approx.):

Given a set of samples (x[i], y[i]) which are supposed to lie on a
line given by 'y = m*x + a'. That is, the estimated line is determined by 'm' and 'a'.
The error between the samples and the estimated line may be given by

```
 error(m, a) = sum((m * x[i] + a - y[i]) ** 2, start_i=0, end_i=N)
```

Now, searching for the zero transitions in the derivatives 'd/dm error(m,a)'
and 'd/da error(m,a)' delivers the minimal distance. How could I find the
solution with sympy?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify: 1) I understand your situation such that the `x[i]` and `N` shall be abstract. How would your situation differ from solving a completely abstract linear equation system? Why do you need SymPy for this and what do you expect it to do for you? 2) If I misunderstood this somehow, why do the standard Python `sum` or `sympy.Sum` not work? — Ideally please give some example for the input, what you want to do with it, and what kind of result you would like to have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your later question, I assume you already figured most of it, but for clarity sake, samples are considered as function (makes sense, given sets are actually functions that cover the domain of the set [mostly over part of the integers]), so the notation is like `x(i)`, and summation can be achieved with the `summation` function or `Sum` constructor (the first one is better, since it will expand automatically constant addends, like `summation(x, (i, 0, n))`).

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> m, a, x, y, i, n = symbols('m a x y i n')
>>> err = summation((m * x(i) + a - y(i)) ** 2, (i, 0, n))
>>> pprint(err)
  n
 ___
 ╲
  ╲                      2
  ╱   (a + m⋅x(i) - y(i))
 ╱
 ‾‾‾
i = 0
```

After you provide the sum function the addend expression and the `(index, lower bound, upper bound)`, you can move on to play with the sum:

```
>>> diff(err, m)
Sum(2*(a + m*x(i) - y(i))*x(i), (i, 0, n))
>>> diff(err, a)
Sum(2*a + 2*m*x(i) - 2*y(i), (i, 0, n))
```

Comment: This throws a "TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not callable"

Comment: @Scott I wrote this answer almost 3 years ago. Maybe a newer version of sympy has deprecated default symbol subscription? (That'd be my first guess)

Comment: @Scott 
m, a, i, n = symbols('m a x y i n')
err, x, y = symbols('err x y', cls=Function)

should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution is to used `IndexedBased` symbols and an integer symbol for the index of the summation, and the `Sum` instance with appropriate setup, i.e.

```
from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Sum, expand

x = IndexedBase('x')
y = IndexedBase('y')
n, m, a = symbols('n m a')
i = symbols('i', integer=True)

expr = Sum((m * x[i] + a - y[i]) ** 2, (i, 1, n))
```

From there, you can make any modifications as you would do on paper, namely for example:

```
print(expand(expr))
```